# How to install windows service as current user

Tags: java, windows, powershell, cmd, procrun

The code below is used in Java to create Windows service.

When I run the batch file with jar its installing service as system.
Can anyone please help how to install the service as current user?

> user = "xyz"

Is Windows login password necessary?

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { installFolder+"/UninstallerAgent.exe",
    "//IS//UninstallerAgent", 
    "--Install=" + installFolder + "/Uninstaller.exe",
    "--DisplayName=UninstallerAgentv1.1",
    "--Jvm=" + installFolder + "/runtime/bin/j9vm/jvm.dll", 
    "--Classpath=" + installFolder + "/UninstallerAgent.jar",
    "--Startup=auto",
    "--StartMode=jvm",
    "--StartClass=com.uninstaller.Main",
    "--StartMethod=\"start\"",
    "--StartParams=\"start\"",
    "--StopMode=jvm",
    "--StopClass=com.uninstaller.Main",
    "--StopMethod=\"stop\"",
    "--StopParams=\"stop\"",
    "--LogLevel=Error",
    "--LogJniMessages=0",
    "--LogPath="+installFolder,
    "--LogPrefix=\"UninstallerAgentService\"",
    "--StdOutput=auto",
    "--StdError=auto",
    "--Description=\"Local Probe for finding IP and Serial ID\""                
});
```

Comment: That must then be a feature of your `UninstallerAgent.exe` - try to find it's documentation.

Comment: i used prunsrv.exe  . renamed as  UninstallerAgent.exe.

Comment: --User command is there but not getting how can use in my code

Comment: @user3312405 use the `--ServiceUser` and `--ServicePassword` options

Comment: "--ServiceUser=xyz"  tried like this but still installing as system

Comment: used like this.. its installing service as current user     process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { installFolder+"/UninstallerAgent.exe",
                "//IS//UninstallerAgent", 
                "--ServiceUser="+System.getProperty("user.name"),

Comment: but when it start running it will automatically change to system in task manager     try{
                    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {installFolder+"/UninstallerAgent.exe","//RS//UninstallerAgent"});
                    Thread.sleep(15000);
                   System.out.println("runnig Service...");
                    process.getOutputStream().close();
                   }catch(Exception ex2){
                  //ignore
                   }

Comment: You must provide the password as well as the username.

Comment: process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { installFolder+"/UninstallerAgent.exe", "//IS//UninstallerAgent", "--ServiceUser="+System.getProperty("user.name"), "--ServicePassword=user123"     tried like this . process is not created

Comment: I felt [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html) is best in this case.